# Draggable border to resize view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, widget, android-view

The past few months I've been on a mission to implement widget support in my home screen replacement for Android, and it's proving rather difficult. I can now add and remove widgets to/from the home screen, but they can't be resized or moved yet. Currently what I'm trying to achieve is to resize them. To do this I have every widget embedded in a View, over which I put an overlay to make sure the touch events don't get caught by the widget underneath it (which caused trouble in past attempts).

What I have now is this layout for the container; http://www.hastebin.com/uwocaxukel.xml

The widget is put in the `FrameLayout` with id `widgetContainer`. As you can see in the screenshot below there is an orange dot in the middle of every border.

[image: Screenshot with one widget]

Now what I've always tried to do so far is catch touch events, figure out whether the user is trying to drag one of the borders (`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`), and if he is, change the required properties in the `LayoutParams` object and call `this.requestLayout ()` on the view. This is finicky, and less than ideal. Very often the touch events would stop registering because the user dragged faster than the view could refresh = user is no longer on the view which is listening for touch events, or the border would be too thin to hit.

So far it's all been very finicky. But there are other apps which seem to do this pretty much perfectly. Is there a library, a class I've overlooked, or something else I can use to achieve my goal?

This is an example of something that kind of worked, but was very finicky and just not remotely user-friendly; https://github.com/RobinJ1995/be.robinj.ubuntu/blob/869d48af2e7a3d8f0332f84edd2a8cd28564424a/UbuntuLauncher/app/src/main/java/be/robinj/ubuntu/widgets/WidgetHostView.java#L75

Comment: "To do this I have every widget embedded in a View, over which I put an overlay to make sure the touch events don't get caught by the widget underneath it" -- why not replace the app widget with a static image during the resize operation? "This is finicky, and less than ideal" -- there are a bunch of image cropping libraries out there that offer draggable crop rectangles. If I had to do this, I'd start there for inspiration.

Comment: @CommonsWare It would be a possibility, but I just thought it looked better if you could still see the widget through the (transparent) overlay. Doesn't really make a difference. Yes, but as you mentioned those are all for images. I can have a look at their source code, I guess. But it just seemed strange to me that there would be no ready-made way to achieve this.

Comment: "but I just thought it looked better if you could still see the widget through the (transparent) overlay" -- sorry, by "static image" I meant "a static image of the app widget, showing its state right before you do the resize operation". "But it just seemed strange to me that there would be no ready-made way to achieve this" -- if by "ready-made" you mean "in the Android SDK", what you are looking to do is not especially common. If by "ready-made" you mean " a third-party library", I haven't looked for one specifically on app widget resizing.

Comment: @RobinJ have you solved the issue and found a good and useable way to resize the widget? If so, would you mind posting your final solution?

Comment: @prom85 Nope. No documentation and seemingly no libraries either. Gotta wonder how the big home screen replacement developers do it. But to be honest I somewhat syspect that all of those custom home screen replacements with proper widget support are just based off the open-source default Android home screen, as this would give them a working widget implementation from the start.